# Default values for higher order components in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

Say I have a higher order component:

```
interface MyHOCInterface { title: string }

export function wrapMyHoc<T extends MyHOCInterface>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<T>,) {
  return class extends React.Component<T> {
    state = {...this.props,}
    const {title} = {...(this.props as T)}
    render() {
      return(
        <>
          {title}
          <Component {...this.props as T} />
        </>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

And then some components that I define like this:

```
export const MyFirstComponent = wrapMyHoc(
  (props: MyHocInterface) => (<></>)
)

export const MySecondComponent = wrapMyHoc(
  (props: MyHocInterface) => (<></>)
)
```

Naturally, this would allow me to render them like below. I noticed this code (all instances of the `MySecondComponent` component always has the same title):

```
<>
  <MyFirstComponent title='my first title'/>
  <MySecondComponent title='my second title' />
  <MySecondComponent title='my second title' />
  <MySecondComponent title='my second title' />
</>
```

How would I go about putting a default value so I can write the following and still have `my second title` as the title:

```
<> <MySecondComponent /> </>
```

Comment: I don't understand wrapMyHoc, you pass `Component` and never use it, you use `title` but it's never defined.

Comment: @HMR : updated the code. All I am looking for is to have a way to allow *one* type that calls `wrapMyHoc` to always have a default value, and for all other types to not have to specify the default value.

Comment: Something like `if Component of type MySecondComponent props.title = "my second title"` (obviously not working code)

Comment: @HMR: That seems like something would go inside the HOC. I don't want to touch my HOC

Comment: Can you wrap the HOC and set default value for `title` if component passed is `MySecondComponent` and title is undefined? You can't set a default for it in `MySecondComponent` because the class returned by HOC also uses the title somewhere right?

Comment: `You can't set a default for it in MySecondComponent because the class returned by HOC also uses the title somewhere right? `
Correct. But I was wondering if there could be two different HOCs (one for the title and one for everything else) and `MySecondComponent` could just wrap one of them and provide the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment about MySecondComponent usig another HOC, I think you can do it something like this:

```
const doubeWrappedHOC = Component => {
  const HOC = wrapMyHoc(Component);
  return props =>
    props.title === undefined &&
    Component === MySecondComponent
      ? HOC({ ...props, title: defaultValue })
      : HOC(props);
};
```

It is not in TypeScript and `MySecondComponent` has to be in scope/inported but all your components could use this HOC instead of using another HOC just for MyCompnent. If you want to create MyCompnent with a diffeerent HOC then you can leave out `&& Component === MySecondComponent`. Re use logic `wrapMyHoc` again and just set a default for title.